# ipython notebook not opening on windows 7

Tags: python, ipython, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to open ipython notebook after downloading it as part of Anaconda, using Windows 7.

I can open ipython in it's own python terminal but not in the browser. When I run `ìpython notebook` in the command prompt I get the huge error log below.

A lot of the other questions about not being able to load ipython include a fairly obvious missing package indicator but I've not been able to spot anything of use in the log.

Any ideas what might be going wrong or what I can do to fix it?

```
Z:\Anaconda>ipython notebook
[I 14:27:59.766 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\traitlets.py", line 407, in __get__
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'ip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 409, in initialize_subcomman
    self.subapp.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 1015, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 868, in init_webapp
    self.login_handler_class.validate_security(self, ssl_options=ssl_options)
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\auth\login.py", line 88, in validate_security
    if not app.ip:
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\traitlets.py", line 412, in __get__
    value = method()
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\html\notebookapp.py", line 420, in _ip_default
    s = socket.socket()
  File "Z:\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 126, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org
```

Answer (score 0):

What ended up fixing the issue was installing Anaconda on the local C drive, as opposed to a mapped shared drive